# Table name as a PostgreSQL Parameter - syntax error using %I

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have a (rather lengthy) [select query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33715529/calculate-the-angle-of-exterior-rings-postgis-polygons-multipolygons) that I need to run on tables of *unknown names* to return another table. Is there a way to do this using [dynamic commands](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-statements.html)?

I keep getting a syntax error on `%I`:

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION angles(table_name TEXT)
  RETURNS TABLE (id int, name varchar, polygon_num int, point_order int) AS 
$BODY$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'select id,
       name,
       polygon_num,
       point_order as vertex,
       --
       case when point_order = 1
         then last_value(ST_Astext(ST_Makeline(sp,ep))) over (partition by id, polygon_num)
         else lag(ST_Astext(ST_Makeline(sp,ep)),1) over (partition by id, polygon_num order by point_order)
       end ||' - '||ST_Astext(ST_Makeline(sp,ep)) as lines,
       --
       abs(abs(
       case when point_order = 1
         then last_value(degrees(ST_Azimuth(sp,ep))) over (partition by id, polygon_num)
         else lag(degrees(ST_Azimuth(sp,ep)),1) over (partition by id, polygon_num order by point_order)
       end - degrees(ST_Azimuth(sp,ep))) -180 ) as ang
from (-- 2.- extract the endpoints for every 2-point line segment for each linestring
      --     Group polygons from multipolygon
      select id,
             name,
             coalesce(path[1],0) as polygon_num,
             generate_series(1, ST_Npoints(geom)-1) as point_order,
             ST_Pointn(geom, generate_series(1, ST_Npoints(geom)-1)) as sp,
             ST_Pointn(geom, generate_series(2, ST_Npoints(geom)  )) as ep
      from ( -- 1.- Extract the individual linestrings and the Polygon number for later identification
             select id,
                    name,
                    (ST_Dump(ST_Boundary(the_geom))).geom as geom,
                    (ST_Dump(ST_Boundary(the_geom))).path as path -- To identify the polygon
              from %I ) as pointlist ) as segments';


END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Query:

```
SELECT angles('poly_and_multipoly');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're neglecting the `format` function to format your string.

%I is an argument to the `format` function, here you're just trying to execute a literal string that happens to have %I in it.

```
EXECUTE format('UPDATE tbl SET %I = $1 WHERE key = $2', colname)
    USING newvalue, keyvalue;
```

Here, you can see `colname` is an argument to the `format` function, while `newvalue` and `keyvalue` are arguments to the result SQL query.

So, wrap your string in the `format` function with the proper arguments and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks! hm. Looking at the [http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT] I'm not sure what I'm missing. I put in: 'from format('%I', table_name)' and got a **ERROR:  type "I" does not exist**

Comment: You need to wrap the entire statement, not just a portion of it. EXECUTE only work on a simple string. The format function does the actual substitution resulting in a simple string that can then be used by EXECUTE. Notice in my example, I have the entire statement being passed to format.

Comment: Format() seems like a beautiful thing...but the frustration caught up with me. I ended up passing a regular concatenated string  **from ' || $1 || ') as pointlist)** ... but I'll keep working with it. Thanks!